# Using Elastic with Parse.com for full text search?

Tags: parse-platform, elasticsearch

I would like to use Parse.com data with elasticSearch. I was thinking about using Parse's webhooks.

How would you do it?

Comment: Please explain in more details what you're trying to achieve so that we can better help you.

Comment: In fact I don't really know how to start. I was thinking about starting a elastic server on Heroku and using parse.com webhook to send data from parse server to my elastic server and index them. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Btw I new at trying this. I am sorry if my questions can sometimes seem easy.